# XPath sibling extraction

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Example document:

```
<h4 class="bla">July 12</h4>
<p>Tim</p>
<p>Jon</p>
<h4 class="bla">July 13</h4>
<p>James</p>
<p>Eric</p>
<p>Jerry</p>
<p>Susie</p>
<h4 class="date">July 14</h4>
<p>Kami</p>
<p>Darryl</p>
```

What I want to do is grab all **p** nodes that were posted on July 13.  Note that they are siblings of **h4** and not children.  So in this example, I'd like to get the **p** nodes that hold the following names: James, Eric, Jerry, and Susie.

I got close with the following, but it chose all **p** nodes that came after the July 13th **h4** node, since they're all siblings. In other words, it didn't have a stop condition.

```
//h4[string() = 'July 13']/following-sibling::p
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
//p[preceding-sibling::h4[1][. = 'July 13']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//p[preceding-sibling::h4/text() = 'July 13' and following-sibling::h4/text() = 'July 14']
```